How to configure maven with checker-framework Fenum?
I'm trying to integrate the Fenum checker into a java maven project, but am having a lot of trouble getting it to work. I've been working off of the manual, an example gradle project, and this SO question, but with no luck.
I've created a minimum reproducible example here on github, where I define the following "MyFenum" annotation:
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE_USE, ElementType.TYPE_PARAMETER})
@SubtypeOf(FenumTop.class)
public @interface MyFenum { }

The manual says:
9.3 Running the Fenum Checker 
The Fenum Checker can be invoked by running the following commands.

If you define your own annotation(s), provide the name(s) of the annotation(s) through the -Aquals option, using a comma-no-space-separated notation:
  javac -classpath /full/path/to/myProject/bin:/full/path/to/myLibrary/bin \
        -processor org.checkerframework.checker.fenum.FenumChecker \
        -Aquals=myPackage.qual.MyFenum MyFile.java ...
The annotations listed in -Aquals must be accessible to the compiler during compilation. Before you run the Fenum Checker with javac, they must be compiled and on the same path (the classpath or processorpath) as the Checker Framework. It is not sufficient to supply their source files on the command line.

So I then split the maven compile step into two phases:

Compile everything in the org/example/annotations/ folder
Compile everything else

This should make the MyFenum class file available on the classpath in step 2.
So the build part of the pom.xml is:
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <!-- Compile just the annotations -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-annotations</id>
                        <phase>process-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                            <includes>
                                <include>org/example/annotations/**/*.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <!-- Compile everything else; annotation classes should automatically be in the classpath -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile-main</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                            <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
                            <fork>true</fork>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org/example/annotations/**/*.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <path>
                                    <groupId>org.checkerframework</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>checker</artifactId>
                                    <version>3.45.0</version>
                                </path>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <annotationProcessors>
                                <annotationProcessor>org.checkerframework.checker.fenum.FenumChecker</annotationProcessor>
                            </annotationProcessors>
                            <compilerArgs>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-J--add-opens=jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED</arg>
                                <arg>-Aquals=org.example.annotations.MyFenum</arg>
                                <!-- -AqualDirs also doesn't work: -->
                                <!--                                <arg>-AqualDirs=/Users/loganmallory/code/fenum-demo/target/classes/org/example/annotations</arg>-->
                            </compilerArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

But when I build with mvn clean package, I always get this build error:
[ERROR] error: FenumChecker: could not load class for annotation: org.example.annotations.MyFenum. Ensure that it is a type annotation and your classpath is correct.

This error seems to originate from this checker-framework code, but I'm not sure why it can't find the MyFenum.class file on the classpath.
When I run with mvn clean package -X, the classpath looks correct:
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d /Users/loganmallory/code/checker-framework-fenum-demo/target/classes -classpath /Users/loganmallory/code/checker-framework-fenum-demo/target/classes:/Users/loganmallory/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker/3.45.0/checker-3.45.0.jar:/Users/loganmallory/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.45.0/checker-qual-3.45.0.jar: -sourcepath /Users/loganmallory/code/checker-framework-fenum-demo/src/main/java:/Users/loganmallory/code/checker-framework-fenum-demo/target/generated-sources/annotations:/Users/loganmallory/code/checker-framework-fenum-demo/target/generated-sources/annotations: /Users/loganmallory/code/checker-framework-fenum-demo/src/main/java/org/example/Main.java -s /Users/loganmallory/code/checker-framework-fenum-demo/target/generated-sources/annotations -processor org.checkerframework.checker.fenum.FenumChecker -processorpath /Users/loganmallory/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker/3.45.0/checker-3.45.0.jar:/Users/loganmallory/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-qual/3.45.0/checker-qual-3.45.0.jar:/Users/loganmallory/.m2/repository/org/checkerframework/checker-util/3.45.0/checker-util-3.45.0.jar: -g -target 20 -source 20 -encoding UTF-8 -Aquals=org.example.annotations.MyFenum

And to confirm, if I run the two phases manually one at a time:
mvn clean process-sources
mvn compile

I can see that the MyFenum.class file is present in the classpath after mvn clean process-sources:

But then mvn compile still fails with the same error:
[ERROR] error: FenumChecker: could not load class for annotation: org.example.annotations.MyFenum. Ensure that it is a type annotation and your classpath is correct.

Has anyone had any success using the Fenum checker with maven, or know of any public examples?
